# PHP Slim Framework : Slim Application Error when using PDO

Tags: pdo, slim

I want to use `PDO` with my Slim php application. When I use a simple select query and send `json` data to `Twig page`. But I keep getting this error : `Slim Application Error`

This is my code :

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Slim\App;

$container = $app->getContainer();

    $container['view'] = function ($container) {
    $templates = __DIR__ . '/templates/';
    $cache = __DIR__ . '/tmp/views/';
    $view = new Slim\Views\Twig($templates, array('cache' => false));
    return $view;
};

$container['db'] = function ($container) {

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;DBName=dbsat", "root", "");
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $pdo;
};


$app->get('/', function ($request, $response) {

    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * from client where id=:id");
    $sth->bindParam("id", 1);
    $sth->execute();
    $todos = json_encode($sth->fetchAll());

    $data = ['user' => $todos];
    return $this->view->render($response, 'home.twig', $data);
});


$app->get('/login', function ($request, $response) {
    return $this->view->render($response, 'login.twig');
});



$app->run();

?>
```

The problem appears at this line :

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * from client where id=:id");
```

Comment: Enable `debug` to see the actual error?

Comment: @ivanka-todorova I've done that and fixed the error, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was caused by binding param
**Message:** Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

By knowing the error I have fixed it. Thank you all.